# Switch Statement Called Inside Of A Failed If Statement

Tags: c++, if-statement, templates, vector, types

Sorry if the title is misleading or generic. I literally do not know what else to name the title. I have created a function that converts a vector of any type into a string. I have `template<typename K>` prefacing the function code, which is used as a placeholder for the type of the vector. My main problem is the nested switch statements inside of if statements used to check the type of the vector. Even when the if statement checks fail, the code still gives this error: `a switch expression of type 'float' is not valid`. For example, if I had a vector of type `float` declared in main, then I used the function to convert the vector to a string, it would give me two errors. One for the switch statement nested inside the `int` check, and the other for the switch statement nested inside of the `char` check. This is very frustrating as these if checks should fail due to the vector not being an `int` or `char`. Furthermore, they can't be both `int` and `char` at the same time either! I've been trying to dissect my code and figure this problem out, but I've come to no solution. Maybe it's because I'm new to templates and the `std::is_same` function.

Here is my header file code (it's kinda long sry):

```
#include <string>
#include <vector>

//Converts a vector of any type into a string like this: 2, 5, 6, 3, (Yes the comma stays at the end like that. That can be fixed but it will require huge amounts of code)
template<typename K>
std::string convertToString(std::vector<K>& V) {

    std::string result_str{""};

    for (auto s : V) {

        if (std::is_same<K, bool>::value) {

            if (s == true) {

                result_str += "true, ";

            }
            else if (s == false) {

                result_str += "false, ";

            }

        }
        else if (std::is_same<K, int>::value) {

            switch (s) {

            case 1:
                result_str += "1, ";
                break;

            case 2:
                result_str += "2, ";
                break;

            case 3:
                result_str += "3, ";
                break;

            case 4:
                result_str += "4, ";
                break;

            case 5:
                result_str += "5, ";
                break;

            case 6:
                result_str += "6, ";
                break;

            case 7:
                result_str += "7, ";
                break;

            case 8:
                result_str += "8, ";
                break;

            case 9:
                result_str += "9, ";
                break;

            default:
                result_str += "Not a digit, ";

            }

        }
        else if (std::is_same<K, float>::value) {

            //Because switch statements cannot take floating point values (For some reason I thought this would fix my problem but it didn't)
            if (s == 1) {

                result_str += "1, ";

            }
            else if (s == 2) {

                result_str += "2, ";

            }
            else if (s == 3) {

                result_str += "3, ";

            }
            else if (s == 4) {

                result_str += "4, ";

            }
            else if (s == 5) {

                result_str += "5, ";

            }
            else if (s == 6) {

                result_str += "6, ";

            }
            else if (s == 7) {

                result_str += "7, ";

            }
            else if (s == 8) {

                result_str += "8, ";

            }
            else if (s == 9) {

                result_str += "9, ";

            }
            else {
                result_str += "., ";
            }

        }
        else if (std::is_same<K, char>::value) {

            switch (s)
            {
            case 'a': 
                result_str += "a, ";
                break;

            case 'A':
                result_str += "A, ";
                break;

            case 'b': 
                result_str += "b, ";
                break;

            case 'B':
                result_str += "B, ";
                break;

            case 'c': 
                result_str += "c, ";
                break;

            case 'C':
                result_str += "C, ";
                break;

            case 'd': 
                result_str += "d, ";
                break;

            case 'D':
                result_str += "D, ";
                break;

            case 'e': 
                result_str += "e, ";
                break;

            case 'E':
                result_str += "E, ";
                break;

            case 'f': 
                result_str += "f, ";
                break;

            case 'F':
                result_str += "F, ";
                break;

            case 'g': 
                result_str += "g, ";
                break;

            case 'G':
                result_str += "G, ";
                break;

            case 'h':
                result_str += "h, ";
                break;

            case 'H':
                result_str += "H, ";
                break;

            case 'i':
                result_str += "i, ";
                break;

            case 'I':
                result_str += "I, ";
                break;

            case 'j': 
                result_str += "j, ";
                break;

            case 'J':
                result_str += "J, ";
                break;

            case 'k': 
                result_str += "k, ";
                break;

            case 'K':
                result_str += "K, ";
                break;

            case 'l': 
                result_str += "l, ";
                break;

            case 'L':
                result_str += "L, ";
                break;

            case 'm': 
                result_str += "m, ";
                break;

            case 'M':
                result_str += "M, ";
                break;

            case 'n': 
                result_str += "n, ";
                break;

            case 'N':
                result_str += "N, ";
                break;

            case 'o': 
                result_str += "o, ";
                break;

            case 'O':
                result_str += "O, ";
                break;

            case 'p': 
                result_str += "p, ";
                break;

            case 'P':
                result_str += "P, ";
                break;

            case 'q': 
                result_str += "q, ";
                break;

            case 'Q':
                result_str += "Q, ";
                break;

            case 'r': 
                result_str += "r, ";
                break;

            case 'R':
                result_str += "R, ";
                break;

            case 's': 
                result_str += "s, ";
                break;

            case 'S':
                result_str += "S, ";
                break;

            case 't': 
                result_str += "t, ";
                break;

            case 'T':
                result_str += "T, ";
                break;

            case 'u': 
                result_str += "u, ";
                break;

            case 'U':
                result_str += "U, ";
                break;

            case 'v': 
                result_str += "v, ";
                break;

            case 'V':
                result_str += "V, ";
                break;

            case 'w': 
                result_str += "w, ";
                break;

            case 'W':
                result_str += "W, ";
                break;

            case 'x':
                result_str += "x, ";
                break;

            case 'X':
                result_str += "X, ";
                break;

            case 'y': 
                result_str += "y, ";
                break;

            case 'Y':
                result_str += "Y, ";
                break;

            case 'z': 
                result_str += "z, ";
                break;

            case 'Z':
                result_str += "Z, ";
                break;
            }

        }

    }

    return result_str;

}
```

Here is my cpp file code:

```
#include "Helper.h"
#include <iostream>

std::vector<float> nums{ 2.4, 65.2, 56.3, 4.6 };

int main() {

    std::cout << convertToString(nums);

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well you are using a float vector , so when compiler compiles the code it replaces the template version with float version so the line `switch (s)` is using float in a switch statement, as for solution here is a simplified version using string streams

```
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>

std::vector<float> nums{2.4, 65.2, 56.3, 4.6};
std::vector<bool> b{true, false, false};
std::vector<int> i{1,2,3,4,5};
//Converts a vector of any type into a string like this: 2, 5, 6, 3, (Yes the comma stays at the end like that. That can be fixed but it will require huge amounts of code)
template <typename K>
std::string convertToString(std::vector<K> &V)
{
    std::string result_str{""};
    for (auto s : V)
    {
            std::stringstream converter;
            converter << std::boolalpha << s; 
            result_str += converter.str() + ", ";

    }
    return result_str;
}

int main()
{
    std::cout<< convertToString(b)<<std::endl;
    std::cout<< convertToString(nums)<<std::endl;
    std::cout<< convertToString(i)<<std::endl;
}
```

you can follow up with a substring operation to remove the last comma if needed.

Comment: Thank you! This is much simpler and easier to understand than Casey's version, even though Casey's version still works well and is very usable.

Comment: @HyperTextMarkupMan  if you are satisfied with the resolution please accept and close, also you want to look into string streams they are very powerful and comes with input manipulators like `boolalpha` I used  and other , for this type of operations

Answer (score 0):

I think the compiler checks the switch expr during compilation.
Maybe you could use some string methods to do this, just like that
`else if (std::is_same<K, char>::value) { result_str.push_back(s); }`

`else if (std::is_same<K, int>::value) { result_str.append(std::to_string(s)); }`

Comment: I thought about using if/else logic, but it seemed a little unnecessary if I could just use the switch statement. What I'm trying to figure out is why would the compiler check the switch statement if the "if" statement evaluates to false? Wouldn't the compiler just completely skip over it?

Answer (score 0):

I think you're over-complicating things. You can leverage `std::to_string` and the type trait checkers to do most of the work:

```cpp
#include <string>
#include <type_traits>
#include <vector>

template<typename K>
std::string convertToString_helper(K s) {
    //Test from most specific to least to prevent bool and char being converted incorrectly.
    if constexpr(std::is_same_v<K, bool>) {
        return s ? std::string{"true"} : std::string{"false"};
    } else if constexpr(std::is_same_v<K, char>) {
        return std::string{s};
    } else if constexpr(std::is_integral_v<K> || std::is_floating_point_v<K>) {
        return std::to_string(s);
    } else if constexpr(std::is_convertible_v<K, std::string>) {
        return s;
    } else {
        return "Not convertible to a string";
    }
}

template<typename K>
std::string convertToString(std::vector<K>& V) {
    std::string result{};
    for(auto iter = std::cbegin(V); iter != std::cend(V) - 1; ++iter) {
        result += convertToString_helper(*iter) + ", ";
    }
    auto last_iter = std::cend(V) - 1;
    result += convertToString_helper(*last_iter);
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Your functions are actually more complicated than mine it's just that my function is longer.  Also, what is constexpr doing in `convertToString_helper()`?

Comment: And why are you using pointers when you put things into `convertToString_helper()`?

Comment: @HyperTextMarkupMan Not pointers. Iterators. They require being dereferenced to get to the underlying value.

Comment: @HyperTextMarkupMan `convertToString_helper` prevents repeating duplicate code just to not append a comma at the end.

Comment: so the pointers aren't actually acting like pointers in that scenario?

Also I know that `convertToString_helper` prevents repeating duplicate code just to not append a comma at the end but what does `constexpr` do in the function? I've never used `constexpr` before in any of my programs so if I am going to use that function it would be helpful to know how it works.

Comment: @HyperTextMarkupMan See [cppreference.com section on constexpr if](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/if#Constexpr_If)

Comment: Thank you, I guess I didn't think about looking it up sorry